# Is an Ultra Super Saiyan physically as strong as a Super Saiyan 2?

Tags: dragon-ball

In the show Trunks powered up to Ultra Super Saiyan, and was stronger than Cell but not fast enough to hit him. It occurred to me. In a test of strength, like an arm-wrestling match or a weight-lifting contest, could a USSJ beat a Super Saiyan 2?

Comment: In terms of "power level" alone, SSJ2 is much stronger than USSJ (which is a 3rd stamina/strength level within SSJ). So, regardless of the strength boost of USSJ, it's not as strong as SSJ2.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on the anime stackexchange?

Comment: @DoctorWho22 Is it on-topic there? Yes. Is it on-topic here? Yes. Is it a better fit there? Not necessarily. We deal with anime and manga as well - provided there is a sci-fi/fantasy element involved. It may find more answers there, but that doesn't mean it's not allowed here.

Comment: Well now that there's a anime / manga stackexchange it would be reasonable for those sorts of questions to be put on that instead of on here... Dragonball Z is not science fiction the only thing it could possibly be is a form of fantasy only because it's a fictional universe that has some forms of magic / supernatural things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can't be determined because we don't know the physical feats of Ultra Super Saiyan versus a Super Saiyan 2.

We do however know that Trunks became physically stronger but did not increase his speed when he achieved USSJ.

Super Saiyan 2 is both physically stronger and faster, though it is unspecified whether or not USSJ is physically stronger than SSJ2... But as somebody commented the power level of SSJ2 is more than that of the USSJ.